# How to handle Lightning Web Component Event from Lightning Aura Component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I am firing an event from my Lightning Web Component(LWC). Now I have to receive this event by a Aura Component.

As per the documentation I am able to receive the event if this LWC is enclosed in the Aura Component.

But I am not able to handle this event if LWC and Aura components are independents (LWC is not enclosed in the Aura Component).

I am firing event through Publish Subscriber model.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

To simplify things, lets call your LWC, component A, and your Aura component, component B.

Currently your components are independent, thus in tree terms, your component B (Aura) is not an [ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094991/basic-tree-concept-defining-ancestors) of the component A (LWC).

There are two quick ways you could fire an event from component A (LWC) to component B (Aura)

1) Create a new Aura component that encapsulates component A (LWC). Component A then would fire a standard DOM event and the new Aura component would listen for the event and then re-fire the event as an application [Aura event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_fire.htm). Component B would then listen for the event and handle it. Something like this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kmesic/020a8c8e5efa703b319e0f14ac9a4b69).

2) Create a child LWC component, call it componentC,  in component B (Aura). Fire the event via pub-sub in component A (LWC). Then in componentC, listen and handle your event then re-fire it as a standard DOM event that would be handled by your Aura component, component B.

More resources:

[Events in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch),
[Event Propagation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_propagation),
[Events from LWC -> Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components)